# Show title bar only on archives / hide it on all posts and pages

Tags: customization, archives

My theme has a title bar below the menu. The title bar displays the Title and a breadcrumbs menu. The code is in a template file called title-bar.php. The title bar now shows up on all pages and on all posts.

I want this title bar only to show up on all my custom post type archive pages, but hide it on all other pages and on all single posts including custom post types.

How can I do this?

IF page type is ARCHIVE: (code for title bar)

ELSE: (empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_post_type_archive()`, which is one of the many [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) in WordPress:

```php
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'your_post_type' ) ) {
  // show the title bar
}
// else, just do nothing
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you!